# How to set the Inviter using devise_inevitable gem in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

I am working on rails 4 and setup devise_invitable gem recently. I have a Student and Teachers models in which Student get invited by Teacher means Teacher is Inviter and Student is Invitee.

I have added all necessary columns in students table like this:

```
    t.string   "invitation_token"
    t.datetime "invitation_created_at"
    t.datetime "invitation_sent_at"
    t.datetime "invitation_accepted_at"
    t.integer  "invitation_limit"
    t.integer  "invited_by_id"
    t.string   "invited_by_type"
    t.integer  "invitations_count",      default: 0
```

I login through Teachers account and now want to invite a student, when I click on link to invite a student then it goes to path: "/students/invitation/new" and request me to login as a student which does't make sense because I want to invite student then why do I need to login as student even Teacher session is already there and it should use teacher object to invite student.

I even try below code but it does't work:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
     include DeviseInvitable::Inviter
  end
```

Here are my routes:

```
                    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                           Controller#Action
        new_student_session GET    /students/login(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
            student_session POST   /students/login(.:format)             devise/sessions#create
    destroy_student_session DELETE /students/logout(.:format)            devise/sessions#destroy
           student_password POST   /students/password(.:format)          devise/passwords#create
       new_student_password GET    /students/password/new(.:format)      devise/passwords#new
      edit_student_password GET    /students/password/edit(.:format)     devise/passwords#edit
                            PATCH  /students/password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
                            PUT    /students/password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
cancel_student_registration GET    /students/cancel(.:format)            devise_invitable/registrations#cancel
       student_registration POST   /students(.:format)                   devise_invitable/registrations#create
   new_student_registration GET    /students/sign_up(.:format)           devise_invitable/registrations#new
  edit_student_registration GET    /students/edit(.:format)              devise_invitable/registrations#edit
                            PATCH  /students(.:format)                   devise_invitable/registrations#update
                            PUT    /students(.:format)                   devise_invitable/registrations#update
                            DELETE /students(.:format)                   devise_invitable/registrations#destroy
  accept_student_invitation GET    /students/invitation/accept(.:format) devise/invitations#edit
  remove_student_invitation GET    /students/invitation/remove(.:format) devise/invitations#destroy
         student_invitation POST   /students/invitation(.:format)        devise/invitations#create
     new_student_invitation GET    /students/invitation/new(.:format)    devise/invitations#new
                            PATCH  /students/invitation(.:format)        devise/invitations#update
                            PUT    /students/invitation(.:format)        devise/invitations#update
        new_teacher_session GET    /teachers/login(.:format)             devise/sessions#new
            teacher_session POST   /teachers/login(.:format)             devise/sessions#create
    destroy_teacher_session DELETE /teachers/logout(.:format)            devise/sessions#destroy
           teacher_password POST   /teachers/password(.:format)          devise/passwords#create
       new_teacher_password GET    /teachers/password/new(.:format)      devise/passwords#new
      edit_teacher_password GET    /teachers/password/edit(.:format)     devise/passwords#edit
                            PATCH  /teachers/password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
                            PUT    /teachers/password(.:format)          devise/passwords#update
cancel_teacher_registration GET    /teachers/cancel(.:format)            devise_invitable/registrations#cancel
       teacher_registration POST   /teachers(.:format)                   devise_invitable/registrations#create
   new_teacher_registration GET    /teachers/sign_up(.:format)           devise_invitable/registrations#new
  edit_teacher_registration GET    /teachers/edit(.:format)              devise_invitable/registrations#edit
                            PATCH  /teachers(.:format)                   devise_invitable/registrations#update
                            PUT    /teachers(.:format)                   devise_invitable/registrations#update
                            DELETE /teachers(.:format)                   devise_invitable/registrations#destroy
           new_user_session GET    /users/login(.:format)                devise/sessions#new
               user_session POST   /users/login(.:format)                devise/sessions#create
       destroy_user_session DELETE /users/logout(.:format)               devise/sessions#destroy
              user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#create
          new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)         devise/passwords#new
         edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)        devise/passwords#edit
                            PATCH  /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#update
                            PUT    /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#update
   cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)               devise_invitable/registrations#cancel
          user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                      devise_invitable/registrations#create
      new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)              devise_invitable/registrations#new
     edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                 devise_invitable/registrations#edit
                            PATCH  /users(.:format)                      devise_invitable/registrations#update
                            PUT    /users(.:format)                      devise_invitable/registrations#update
                            DELETE /users(.:format)                      devise_invitable/registrations#destroy
          static_pages_home GET    /static_pages/home(.:format)          static_pages#home
         dashboard_teachers GET    /teachers/dashboard(.:format)         teachers#dashboard
                       root GET    /                                     static_pages#home
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :students, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}
  devise_for :teachers, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}
  devise_for :users, path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}
  get 'static_pages/home'

  resources :teachers, only: [] do 
  collection do
    get :dashboard
  end
  end  


   root 'static_pages#home'

end
```

Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: Shouldn't you use User as a model, separated by role Student, Teachers?

Comment: Teacher and student are separate models rather role of User.

Comment: can you paste the out put of  `rake routes`

Comment: @Ronak Jain routes are added in Question Description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override authenticate_inviter method of gem in Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protected
  def authenticate_inviter!
    authenticate_teacher!(:force => true)
  end
end
```

And include DeviseInvitable::Inviter module into Teacher model:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :validatable
  include DeviseInvitable::Inviter
end
```

You can define association in model by which you want that all invitations should be sent by this:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :invitations, :class_name => self.to_s, :as => :invited_by
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I lack 7 reputation points to post a comment to your question. So I do it this way.

You have two users, 1) Student 2) Teacher. Why do you have 3 ways to log in?

Anyway I guess you want only the teacher to be able to send invitations to students. As I see it now, you made your routes so that only students can send invitations to students So why not change your routes?

Comment: Why did you lose your points?

Teacher Can login to see its own details, same for Student so that's why we  make them login separately.

How can I get change my routes?

Comment: But you also have a User login. What can a user do? Can you show me the routes.rb

Comment: User have different roles like Super Admin, Admin etc.

Routes are added in Question Description.